# Required macro excel code for search and copy paste query

Tags: excel, vba, search, copy

I need to write a vba macro code in excel
I need to search for word " item" in column A and if found I need to copy data in "C2" and paste from "B3" to until the next word " item" is found and again I need to find next word " item" and copy paste as before in column "B"
I have attached a screen shot of inputs and outputs

Can any one support to write a vba code so it will be helpful for my daily activities..[i/p o/p data screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9T88.jpg)

Comment: You don't need a macro for this. A formula can do it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your info spyros and i need either macro or formula to solve my query can u let me know the formula for my query

Comment: Done, That's my formula anyway.. Someone more expert or if I had time, would make a more exwuiisite eloquent one. Principal is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(E6="","",IF(AND(LEN(E5)>1,LEN(F5)<1),IF(AND(LEN(G6)<1,LEN(F6)<1),"",E5),D5))
```

or,

```
=IF(LEN(E5)<1,"",IF(AND(LEN(E4)>1,LEN(F4)<1),IF(AND(LEN(G5)<1,LEN(F5)<1),"",E4),D4))
```

drag down

[image]

This kind of approach solves alot of problems. Let me know if works for you - it should - and if my answer answers your question can you mark the tick box? A Macro would take more time to make. Writing a formula is faster, but one could adapt the formula (its process) into a macro too.

Plus, With the formula hiding/placed in column B you can see the cells updating as you input your data into your sheet.